# collapse all code cells by default (sas kernel)

Tags: sas, jupyter-notebook, saspy

I am aware of [this](http://chris-said.io/2016/02/13/how-to-make-polished-jupyter-presentations-with-optional-code-visibility/) but I have to use the [sas kernel](https://github.com/sassoftware/sas_kernel). This means that the suggested JavaScript to collapse all code cells by default does not work. How can I collaps all code cells and just show MarkDown and outputs/graphs/tables?

Comment: What type did you set the cell to when setting it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with Jupyter in SAS UE with the SAS kernel.

So I created a cell, with type = Raw NBConvert and then in the cell selected HTML.

Then I added a few test cells with SAS code.

Then I went to Print Preview and there's a button at the top that shows the outputs with the code nodes collapsed (invisible actually) and then you can press the button to have them appear.

Comment: Sorry how do you select HTML when you create a Raw NBConvert cell?

Comment: Actually it works OOTB ignore me. Btw. I am using: options nonotes; However SAS still writes a few things. Can I totally suppress this? Thanks.

Comment: IME Jupyter notebooks don’t show the log. You can control the tables and such with ODS SELECT or ODS EXCLUDE.